# Images not uploading ... sometimes

Tags: bug, chat

I am occasionally getting a

> Failed to upload image, please try again!

error when I try to upload pictures in the chats:

[image: error]

It doesn't state exactly what is the error. I understand that if the picture is gigantic, it might exceed the size limit. Or maybe it is the wrong format. But the strange thing is that when I try to upload normal pictures directly from the phone, sometimes the upload succeeds but other time it fails?

Is there anyway to add more detailed error messages?

Comment: is this question about reporting a bug that sometimes image upload doesn't work or a feature request to add more descriptive error messages when that happens?

Comment: A fix if possible, or a workaround (detailed error message) if fixing the problem becomes too hard for the time being.

Comment: I've had this problem when uploading images that are too large, the upload form times out before it has a chance to tell you that it isn't going to upload your image because it is too big. That may or may not be the problem here.

Comment: Wait, are you uploading from your phone? Which phone is it? This is a problem that I've had a lot as well, but I think it has to do with the nature of the phone itself.

Comment: Mostly from iphone 6 in the recent times. But it did happen a couple of time when I tried to upload from my PC too.